# Benutzt man "manch" mit Singular oder mit Plural?

Tags: pronoun

> - Manch einer könnte jetzt denken,....
> - manch böses Wort */aus dem Duden/*
> - Neue Kulturen und Gebräuche machen manch Deutschen Angst./*Quelle: Facebook*/

Ist beides richtig oder handelt es sich beim dritten Beispielsatz um einen Fehler?

Comment: muss heißen: manchen Deutschen

Comment: @äüö Ist also manch Deutschem falsch?

Comment: Nein, mit m ("machen manch Deutschem Angst") ist es nicht falsch (aber für mich klingt es etwas holprig). Es geht auch "machen manch einem Deutschen Angst". Mit n ("machen manch Deutschen Angst") ist falsch, glaube ich.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Facebook-Satz ist falsch.

---

Das Wort *»manch«* ist ein Indefinitpronomen, das sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural verwendet werden kann. Dabei muss es aber natürlich dekliniert werden. Dabei gibt es aber eine Besonderheit. Das Wort *»manch«* bleibt nämlich in bestimmten Situationen ungebeugt, nämlich:

- vor dem Wort *»andere«* (und davon abgeleiteten Formen)

  > **Manch anderer** wäre wohl vor Lachen explodiert.
  >   **Manch anderes** Kind hätte sich irgendwo versteckt.
- Vor einem attributivem Adjektiv, das seinerseits vor einem Nomen steht

  > **Manch hoher Berg** wurde erst im 20. Jahrhundert erstbestiegen.
  >   **Manch gute Idee** entstand in einem Traum.
- Als feste Fügung mit einem unbestimmten Artikel (als Synonym von *»manche(r)«*)

  > **Manch ein Schüler** weiß mehr als sein Lehrer.
  >   **Manch eine Tanne** landet am Jahresende in einem Wohnzimmer.

Da es unbestimmte Artikel nur im Singular gibt, kann diese Variante nicht im Plural vorkommen. Alle anderen aber sehr wohl:

> **Manch andere** Kinder hätten sich irgendwo versteckt.
>   **Manch gute Ideen** entstanden in einem Traum.

---

Gebeugt kommt das Wort sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural vor:

- Singular

  > **Mancher** Mann trinkt zu viel.
  >   **Manche** Frau isst zu viel.
  >   **Manches** Kind schläft zu viel.
- Plural

  > **Manche** Leute arbeiten zu viel.

---

Der Facebook-Satz passt in keines oben genannten Schemata. Er ist daher falsch.

Comment: Alternativ könnte der Facebooksatz auch "[...] machen manch Deutsche*m* Angst" lauten, oder liege ich da vollkommen falsch?

Comment: Ich vermute, zur Unklarheit, ob *manch* auch für Subjekte im Plural verwendet werden kann, trägt bei, dass in Sätzen wie "Manch deutsche Birne ist bereits zu Schnaps geworden" (Singular!) die Form "manch deutsche..." vorkommt, weshalb man dazu neigen mag, auch "manch Deutsche trinken gerne Birnenschnaps" (Plural!)  für zulässig zu halten - einfach weil der Klang vertraut ist. Kurz: Es *klingt* richtig.

Comment: @tallistroan: Ich habe absichtlich keine korrekten Alternativen angegeben, weil es da so viele Möglichkeiten gibt